# How can I execute multiline sql statements in windows command line with mysql.exe?

Tags: mysql, windows

On Linux shells we can execute sql commands both in one line as multiline:

```
mysql -u username -usecret -e "show databases;use mydatabase;show tables;"
```

```
mysql -u username -usecret -e "show databases;
use mydatabase;
show tables;"
```

But multiline inside the sql script seems not to work in Windows.

How can I execute multiline sql statements in windows? Is there some kind of `<newLine>` for mysql multilines?

```
# the following doesn't work in windows:
mysql.exe -u username -usecret -e "show databases;
use mydatabase;
show tables;"
```

When I use echo and pipe it to `mysql.exe` the ouput is not formatted as a table

```
echo show databases; ^
use mydatabase; ^
show tables; | mysql.exe -u username -usecret
```

it simply outputs

```
Database
information_schema
mydatabase
performance_schema
sys
...
```

and I would expect the following output:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mydatabase         |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `--table` or `-t` for output in table format:

```
echo show databases; ^
use mydatabase; ^
show tables; | mysql.exe -u username -usecret --table
```